# String Output in Python

Tags: python

```
 html_body += "<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td>".\format(p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3])
                                                                                           ^
```

> SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

It looks normal. how should i fix it?

Comment: Put a newline after the `\\`?

Answer (score 1):

```
html_body += "<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td>".\form
                                                                ^
```

Right there is your problem.  The backslash is the line-continuation character that the error mentions.  Take it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
html_body += "<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td>".\format(p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3])
this backslash is not needed ----------------------------------^
```